# Android - Implementing custom Layout with text input

Tags: android, layout, input, custom-controls

**EDIT:** Since the original question is a bit vague, here's the use case I'm shooting for:

I'm trying to make a custom pin entry widget with these constraints...

- Each character has it's own "box"
- The length of the pin (number of boxes) is configurable with an xml attribute - this part I've done already
- A box gets "filled" with an image resource I have instead of a character or a bullet-point like Android uses by default
- The individual boxes should not be focusable; instead, the entire widget is focusable

To meet these design constraints, I'm extending `LinearLayout` and adding child views programmatically based on the pin length attribute I've defined. It goes without saying that I need to hold onto whatever the user has typed. My idea is to use a private `EditText` object internally, forwarding key events to it and and updating the UI by having a `TextWatcher` on the `EditText`.

Has anyone done something like this before? Anyone have tips on how to proceed?

Comment: can you give a bit more info like what you hope to do with this?  It seems odd to type text and not see the text.

Comment: CrazyDart: I want to make a customized pin code entry widget with boxes that aren't individually focusable. The boxes will be "filled" using an image resource.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to [Custom Android pin code entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528592/custom-android-pin-code-entry-widget)

Even though there is no complete answer available yet, it might point anyone into the right direction.