# Custom Android pin code entry widget

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to create a custom pin code widget for android as an alternative to just using an `EditText` with a password inputType attribute. What I'd like to display is a row of boxes, and have each box be filled as the user types his pin.

Someone else did something like this but it turned out to be a fixed number of `EditText` views and there was a lot of **ugly** code for swapping focus as characters were typed or deleted. This is NOT the approach I want to take; rather, I'm designing mine to have **customizable length** (easy) and behave as a **single focusable view** (not so easy).

My concept thus far is some kind of hybrid between a `LinearLayout` (to hold the "boxes") and an `EditText` (to store the user's input).

This is the code so far...

```
public class PinCodeView extends LinearLayout {
    protected static final int MAX_PIN_LENGTH = 10;
    protected static final int MIN_PIN_LENGTH = 1;

    protected int pinLength;
    protected EditText mText;

    public PinCodeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PinCodeView);
        try {
            pinLength = a.getInt(R.styleable.PinCodeView_pinLength, 0);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        pinLength = Math.min(pinLength, MAX_PIN_LENGTH);
        pinLength = Math.max(pinLength, MIN_PIN_LENGTH);

        setupViews();

        Log.d(TAG, "PinCodeView initialized with pinLength = " + pinLength);
    }

    private void setupViews() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < pinLength; i++) {
            // inflate an ImageView and add it
            View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pin_box, null, false);
            addView(child);
        }
    }

    public CharSequence getText() {
        // TODO return pin code text instead
        return null;
    }

    public int length() {
        // TODO return length of typed pin instead
        return pinLength;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        // TODO return an InputConnection
        return null;
    }
}
```

About those overrides: [onCheckIsTextEditor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onCheckIsTextEditor%28%29) should return true and [onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onCreateInputConnection%28android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo%29) should return a new `InputConnection` object to interact with an InputMethod (a keyboard), but that's all I know.

Does anyone know if I'm on the right track? Has anyone done work with `InputConnection` before or made their own editable views able to give guidance?

(Edit 1)
After looking at this some more, it seems I should subclass BaseInputConnection and supply a `TextView` or `EditText` as its target:

```
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        if (!onCheckIsTextEditor()) {
            return null;
        }
        return new BaseInputConnection(mText, true);
    }
```

Assuming this does store the text as it is typed, I still need some way to update the views to reflect the content change...

(Edit 2)
So I added this custom view to a screen for testing. It shows the number of boxes, and the whole view is focusable, but the keyboard never pops up. I know it gains/loses focus because the boxes show highlighting appropriately and I set an `OnFocusChangedListener` to write to logcat.

What makes an actual keyboard appear when an editable view takes focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made considerable progress on this and no longer need help with the InputConnection. In short, you extend `BaseInputConnection` and override `getEditable()` to return an Editable. In this case, I'm returning a private `TextView` used internally by the `PinCodeView`. `PinCodeView` is also overriding several methods like `onKey[foo]()` and forwarding the call to the internal `TextView`. The rest is just using a `TextWatcher` to update one of the child `ImageView`s whenever the text changes.

It works really well. There are still a few minor issues left to polish it up, but I'll address those as separate questions and close this here.

Comment: If you are feeling generous it would be great if this code were made available on github.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: I'd really like to, but it's in use in my company's app, so I don't know that I can release source code for it. Let me check it out with my manager.

Comment: Any update on releasing this on github or if someone else made such progress yet? The code shown here looks really promising and a good starting point for others, though I'd really appreciate the total package. Maybe Android will eventually implement it as another field type :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you might be trying to create an iOS like pin entry view/widget.

Here is a good sample code you may find useful. However, it is fix length, but still maybe useful to some people.

https://github.com/chinloong/Android-PinView

http://madeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-ios-like-pin-entrychallenge.html

Comment: I appreciate your input, and it may be helpful to others, but I've already worked out a solution on my own. Mine is a custom `View` that encapsulates the entire row of boxes, interacts with the Android keyboard, and manages the entire logic itself. It doesn't require a whole activity with an entire layout of buttons and textviews.

Comment: @Karakuri Since you haven't provided source code nor detailed instructions, this answer for pin code entry, is more relevant for me.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has already been answered but since its implementation is not shared i found a similar open source library. It looks good and for all those who wandering can give it try

https://github.com/Philio/PinEntryView

Answer (score 1):

Looks ok to me. Something you might want to do is when a user types a character into one `EditText` box, find a reference to the next EditText box and do a `requestFocus()` on it. This will move the text entry onto the next box. Very simple.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I'm trying to avoid. The entire widget should be focusable, not the individual boxes.

Comment: The individual boxes will need to be focused in order to type into them. Furthermore, an EditText that is in focus will have a blue line around it, showing to the user that it can take input. Without that visual cue the user will not know where his typed characters are going.

Comment: Perhaps this wasn't clear, but I'm NOT using a row of EditTexts and I do NOT want each box to be individually focusable. As I mentioned, I've seen code for that and it's messy and ugly and blech.

This approach is inflating ImageViews for the boxes, and these will have a selector drawable as their background and have duplicateParentState="true" so that they show a focused state when the widget is focused. Bu the key is that the ENTIRE widget gets the focus, not the individual boxes.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I've no idea why you would want to do that. For Android I thought that when a parent has a focused child (i.e. one of the EditText boxes has a focus) then the parent is also considered to be focused. Also I can't imagine the code for that being messy, I am pretty sure it would only require a couple of lines. Good luck though and I think you should define your question a bit more so as not to be confusing.

Comment: Part of it is aesthetics, and part of it is function/behavior. Making each focusable means the user can jump around to any box, but it's a pin code widget, so the actual content is obscured anyway. If you'd like, I could share with you the code that uses the EditTexts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11086/discussion-between-karakuri-and-styx)

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:1.3.10'
```

Put this dependency in your app module Gradle file and sync.

```
    <com.alimuzaffar.lib.pin.PinEntryEditText

                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:id="@+id/Pin_Et"
                    android:maxLength="6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Put this code in XML (layout file).
It works perfectly I use this code