# Custom EditText does not edit item at particular position but start editing from last item always

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making a custom edittext to enter mobile numbers. Here is the code

```
public class PinEntryEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    private static final String XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

    protected String mMask = null;
    protected StringBuilder mMaskChars = null;
    protected String mSingleCharHint = null;
    protected int mAnimatedType = 0;
    protected float mSpace = 24; //24 dp by default, space between the lines
    protected float mCharSize;
    protected float mNumChars = 4;
    protected float mTextBottomPadding = 8; //8dp by default, height of the text from our lines
    protected int mMaxLength = 4;
    protected RectF[] mLineCoords;
    protected float[] mCharBottom;
    protected Paint mCharPaint;
    protected Paint mLastCharPaint;
    protected Paint mSingleCharPaint;
    protected Drawable mPinBackground;
    protected Rect mTextHeight = new Rect();
    protected boolean mIsDigitSquare = false;

    protected View.OnClickListener mClickListener;
    protected OnPinEnteredListener mOnPinEnteredListener = null;

    protected float mLineStroke = 1; //1dp by default
    protected float mLineStrokeSelected = 2; //2dp by default
    protected Paint mLinesPaint;
    protected boolean mAnimate = false;
    protected boolean mHasError = false;
    protected ColorStateList mOriginalTextColors;
    protected int[][] mStates = new int[][]{
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, // selected
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_active}, // error
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, // focused
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused}, // unfocused
    };

    protected int[] mColors = new int[]{
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.RED,
            Color.BLACK,
            Color.GRAY
    };

    protected ColorStateList mColorStates = new ColorStateList(mStates, mColors);

    public PinEntryEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public PinEntryEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
//        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.editTextStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }



    public void setMaxLength(final int maxLength) {
        mMaxLength = maxLength;
        mNumChars = maxLength;

        setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});

        setText(null);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        float multi = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mLineStroke = multi * mLineStroke;
        mLineStrokeSelected = multi * mLineStrokeSelected;
        mSpace = multi * mSpace; //convert to pixels for our density
        mTextBottomPadding = multi * mTextBottomPadding; //convert to pixels for our density

        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PinEntryEditText, 0, 0);
        try {
            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            ta.getValue(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinAnimationType, outValue);
            mAnimatedType = outValue.data;
            mMask = ta.getString(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinCharacterMask);
            mSingleCharHint = ta.getString(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinRepeatedHint);
            mLineStroke = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinLineStroke, mLineStroke);
            mLineStrokeSelected = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinLineStrokeSelected, mLineStrokeSelected);
            mSpace = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinCharacterSpacing, mSpace);
            mTextBottomPadding = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinTextBottomPadding, mTextBottomPadding);
            mIsDigitSquare = ta.getBoolean(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinBackgroundIsSquare, mIsDigitSquare);
            mPinBackground = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinBackgroundDrawable);
            ColorStateList colors = ta.getColorStateList(R.styleable.PinEntryEditText_pinLineColors);
            if (colors != null) {
                mColorStates = colors;
            }
        } finally {
            ta.recycle();
        }

        mCharPaint = new Paint(getPaint());
        mLastCharPaint = new Paint(getPaint());
        mSingleCharPaint = new Paint(getPaint());
        mLinesPaint = new Paint(getPaint());
        mLinesPaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineStroke);

        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorControlActivated,
                outValue, true);
        int colorSelected = outValue.data;
        mColors[0] = colorSelected;

        int colorFocused = isInEditMode() ? Color.GRAY : ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pin_normal);
        mColors[1] = colorFocused;

        int colorUnfocused = isInEditMode() ? Color.GRAY : ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pin_normal);
        mColors[2] = colorUnfocused;

        setBackgroundResource(0);

        mMaxLength = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID, "maxLength", 4);
        mNumChars = mMaxLength;

        //Disable copy paste
        super.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        // When tapped, move cursor to end of text.
        super.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setSelection(getText().length());
                if (mClickListener != null) {
                    mClickListener.onClick(v);
                }
            }
        });

        super.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                setSelection(getText().length());
                return true;
            }
        });

        //If input type is password and no mask is set, use a default mask
        if ((getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD && TextUtils.isEmpty(mMask)) {
            mMask = "\u25CF";
        } else if ((getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD) == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD && TextUtils.isEmpty(mMask)) {
            mMask = "\u25CF";
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mMask)) {
            mMaskChars = getMaskChars();
        }

        //Height of the characters, used if there is a background drawable
        getPaint().getTextBounds("|", 0, 1, mTextHeight);

        mAnimate = mAnimatedType > -1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mOriginalTextColors = getTextColors();
        if (mOriginalTextColors != null) {
            mLastCharPaint.setColor(mOriginalTextColors.getDefaultColor());
            mCharPaint.setColor(mOriginalTextColors.getDefaultColor());
            mSingleCharPaint.setColor(getCurrentHintTextColor());
        }
        int availableWidth = getWidth() - ViewCompat.getPaddingEnd(this) - ViewCompat.getPaddingStart(this);
        if (mSpace < 0) {
            mCharSize = (availableWidth / (mNumChars * 2 - 1));
        } else {
            mCharSize = (availableWidth - (mSpace * (mNumChars - 1))) / mNumChars;
        }
        mLineCoords = new RectF[(int) mNumChars];
        mCharBottom = new float[(int) mNumChars];
        int startX;
        int bottom = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom();
        int rtlFlag;
        final boolean isLayoutRtl = TextUtilsCompat.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale.getDefault()) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
        if (isLayoutRtl) {
            rtlFlag = -1;
            startX = (int) (getWidth() - ViewCompat.getPaddingStart(this) - mCharSize);
        } else {
            rtlFlag = 1;
            startX = ViewCompat.getPaddingStart(this);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mNumChars; i++) {
            mLineCoords[i] = new RectF(startX, bottom, startX + mCharSize, bottom);
            if (mPinBackground != null) {
                if (mIsDigitSquare) {
                    mLineCoords[i].top = getPaddingTop();
                    mLineCoords[i].right = startX + mLineCoords[i].height();
                } else {
                    mLineCoords[i].top -= mTextHeight.height() + mTextBottomPadding * 2;
                }
            }

            if (mSpace < 0) {
                startX += rtlFlag * mCharSize * 2;
            } else {
                startX += rtlFlag * (mCharSize + mSpace);
            }
            mCharBottom[i] = mLineCoords[i].bottom - mTextBottomPadding;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l) {
        mClickListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback) {
        throw new RuntimeException("setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() not supported.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas);
        CharSequence text = getFullText();
        int textLength = text.length();
        float[] textWidths = new float[textLength];
        getPaint().getTextWidths(text, 0, textLength, textWidths);

        float hintWidth = 0;
        if (mSingleCharHint != null) {
            float[] hintWidths = new float[mSingleCharHint.length()];
            getPaint().getTextWidths(mSingleCharHint, hintWidths);
            for (float i : hintWidths) {
                hintWidth += i;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mNumChars; i++) {
            //If a background for the pin characters is specified, it should be behind the characters.
            if (mPinBackground != null) {
                updateDrawableState(i < textLength, i == textLength);
                mPinBackground.setBounds((int) mLineCoords[i].left, (int) mLineCoords[i].top, (int) mLineCoords[i].right, (int) mLineCoords[i].bottom);
                mPinBackground.draw(canvas);
            }
            float middle = mLineCoords[i].left + mCharSize / 2;
            if (textLength > i) {
                if (!mAnimate || i != textLength - 1) {
                    canvas.drawText(text, i, i + 1, middle - textWidths[i] / 2, mCharBottom[i], mCharPaint);
                } else {
                    canvas.drawText(text, i, i + 1, middle - textWidths[i] / 2, mCharBottom[i], mLastCharPaint);
                }
            } else if (mSingleCharHint != null) {
                canvas.drawText(mSingleCharHint, middle - hintWidth / 2, mCharBottom[i], mSingleCharPaint);
            }
            //The lines should be in front of the text (because that's how I want it).
            if (mPinBackground == null) {
                updateColorForLines(i <= textLength);
                canvas.drawLine(mLineCoords[i].left, mLineCoords[i].top, mLineCoords[i].right, mLineCoords[i].bottom, mLinesPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    private CharSequence getFullText() {
        if (mMask == null) {
            return getText();
        } else {
            return getMaskChars();
        }
    }

    private StringBuilder getMaskChars() {
        if (mMaskChars == null) {
            mMaskChars = new StringBuilder();
        }
        int textLength = getText().length();
        while (mMaskChars.length() != textLength) {
            if (mMaskChars.length() < textLength) {
                mMaskChars.append(mMask);
            } else {
                mMaskChars.deleteCharAt(mMaskChars.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        return mMaskChars;
    }


    private int getColorForState(int... states) {
        return mColorStates.getColorForState(states, Color.GRAY);
    }

    /**
     * @param hasTextOrIsNext Is the color for a character that has been typed or is
     *                        the next character to be typed?
     */
    protected void updateColorForLines(boolean hasTextOrIsNext) {
        if (mHasError) {
            mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(android.R.attr.state_active));
        } else if (isFocused()) {
            mLinesPaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineStrokeSelected);
            mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(android.R.attr.state_focused));
            if (hasTextOrIsNext) {
                mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(android.R.attr.state_selected));
            }
        } else {
            mLinesPaint.setStrokeWidth(mLineStroke);
            mLinesPaint.setColor(getColorForState(-android.R.attr.state_focused));
        }
    }

    protected void updateDrawableState(boolean hasText, boolean isNext) {
        if (mHasError) {
            mPinBackground.setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_active});
        } else if (isFocused()) {
            mPinBackground.setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused});
            if (isNext) {
                mPinBackground.setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_selected});
            } else if (hasText) {
                mPinBackground.setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_checked});
            }
        } else {
            mPinBackground.setState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused});
        }
    }

    public void setError(boolean hasError) {
        mHasError = hasError;
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return mHasError;
    }

    /**
     * Request focus on this PinEntryEditText
     */
    public void focus() {
        requestFocus();

        // Show keyboard
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, final int start, int lengthBefore, final int lengthAfter) {
        setError(false);
        if (mLineCoords == null || !mAnimate) {
            if (mOnPinEnteredListener != null && text.length() == mMaxLength) {
                mOnPinEnteredListener.onPinEntered(text);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (mAnimatedType == -1) {
            invalidate();
            return;
        }

        if (lengthAfter > lengthBefore) {
            if (mAnimatedType == 0) {
                animatePopIn();
            } else {
                animateBottomUp(text, start);
            }
        }
    }

    private void animatePopIn() {
        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, getPaint().getTextSize());
        va.setDuration(200);
        va.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                mLastCharPaint.setTextSize((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                PinEntryEditText.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
        if (getText().length() == mMaxLength && mOnPinEnteredListener != null) {
            va.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mOnPinEnteredListener.onPinEntered(getText());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }
            });
        }
        va.start();
    }

    private void animateBottomUp(CharSequence text, final int start) {
        mCharBottom[start] = mLineCoords[start].bottom - mTextBottomPadding;
        ValueAnimator animUp = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mCharBottom[start] + getPaint().getTextSize(), mCharBottom[start]);
        animUp.setDuration(300);
        animUp.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        animUp.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                mCharBottom[start] = value;
                PinEntryEditText.this.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mLastCharPaint.setAlpha(255);
        ValueAnimator animAlpha = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 255);
        animAlpha.setDuration(300);
        animAlpha.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                mLastCharPaint.setAlpha(value);
            }
        });

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        if (text.length() == mMaxLength && mOnPinEnteredListener != null) {
            set.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mOnPinEnteredListener.onPinEntered(getText());
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
        }
        set.playTogether(animUp, animAlpha);
        set.start();
    }

    public void setAnimateText(boolean animate) {
        mAnimate = animate;
    }

    public void setOnPinEnteredListener(OnPinEnteredListener l) {
        mOnPinEnteredListener = l;
    }

    public interface OnPinEnteredListener {
        void onPinEntered(CharSequence str);
    }
}
```

Following is the xml

```
<com.cartoon.customLayout.PinEntryEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_activity_mobile_pinEntryEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number|phone"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.40"
        app:pinAnimationType="fromBottom"
        app:pinBackgroundDrawable="@drawable/bg_pin"
        app:pinCharacterSpacing="4dp" />
```

Suppose the user enters his mobile number and the second digit entered is wrong then the problem is, he/she has to erase the entered characters leading to the second character for a change.

I went through the following posts but they are of no help

[Custom EditText is not showing keyboard on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848748/custom-edittext-is-not-showing-keyboard-on-focus)

[Custom Android pin code entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528592/custom-android-pin-code-entry-widget)

https://github.com/ChaosLeong/PinView

Setting focusable, clickable or focusableInTouchMode does not work. Tried both in XML and code.

The below library does solve my problem but it has some other problem for which I have raised an issue

https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview

Issue: https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/android-otpview-pinview/issues/26

Of course I could take 10 `edittext` and achieve the result which I want but that is not the right way and I will resort to that option in case I am not able to find the right solution to this one.

Comment: Did you try `android:cursorVisible="true"` ,  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or `wrap_content` , `android:textIsSelectable="true"` and check if your `app:pinBackgroundDrawable="@drawable/bg_pin"` is not confliciting with cursor color.

Comment: If you are trying to display PinLockView then I recommend you also check this [library](https://github.com/aritraroy/PinLockView)

Comment: @ravi setting cursorvisible and android:textIsSelectable to true shows the cursor but the functionality is not proper. If i remove drawable/bg_pin then also the functionalit is not proper. I am using contraint layout so width is 0dp

Comment: @ravi the library you mentioned is not quite useful in my case as i want to show the custom edittext in a different format

Comment: Hmm. okay so when you do `cursorVisible` and `textIsSelectable`, the cursor is visible. Its just you want to be able to tap anywhere within the `EditText` to edit that particular character?

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: @ravi Setting the cursorVisible to true shows the cursor but the user needs to tap on the edittext to see the cursor and even after that it does not edit the particular item but deletes last item on pressing cancel on keyboard

Comment: What is "Cancel on keyboard"? Could not understand what you meant there

Comment: @ravi The cross button which is on the keyboard to edit the edittext

Comment: Check that the cursor is not the same color as the background. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: @Cheticamp I am able to see the cursor. Thats not the issue I am facing. The issue is if I entered all the 10 numbers in the edit text and now I want to edit the 5th number only, even after placing the cursor on the 5th number, the deletion starts from the end i.e from the 10th number and not from the 5th number.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your java code. As mentioned in the comment just remove this from the `init()` method.

```
// When tapped, move cursor to end of text.
super.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setSelection(getText().length());
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener.onClick(v);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make the following changes:

In your `PinEntryEditText` class:

```
// When tapped, move cursor to end of text.
    super.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //setSelection(getText().length());
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener.onClick(v);
            }
        }
    });
```

I think `setSelection(getText().length());` was setting selection to the end of the `EditText` no matter where the click even occured.

And in your XML, do these: `android:cursorVisible="true"` and `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Comment: what is mClickListener?

Comment: That is a member variable for handling click event on your `PinEntryEditText` class.

Comment: The problem is that you are using a Custom java class that extends the `EditText` view class. I do not beleive that you have written the whole java class by yourself. Once you decide to go this route, you should make sure that your custom java class is from a reputed developer and has properly commented the code. If either is not true in this case, you should read all the code in your java class to make sure you are not overriding the functions that you do not require.